# Need to separate row using sed or awk command in Solaris

Tags: bash, awk, sed, solaris-10

I have the following data in one line.

```
2014-12-30 00:00:02,317 pool-14076-thread-3 DEBUG [com.fundamo.connector.airtime.service.AirtimeService] ERS Response XML - <soap:Envelope><soap:Body><TopUpPhoneAccountResult><MessageID>1913351092</MessageID><MessageRefID>BD9123000000003</MessageRefID><TopUpPhoneAccountStatus><StatusID>200</StatusID><Comment>Transaction Successful</Comment></TopUpPhoneAccountStatus><TopUpPhoneAccountAmountSent><Amount>2000</Amount><AmountExcludingTax>2000</AmountExcludingTax><TaxName/><TaxAmount>0</TaxAmount><PhoneNumber>1766910910</PhoneNumber><ResponseDateTime>20141230000002320</ResponseDateTime><ServiceType>PRETOP</ServiceType><CurrencyCode>TK</CurrencyCode></TopUpPhoneAccountAmountSent></TopUpPhoneAccountResult></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>
```

Now I want to take a few values from them. I used this command:

```
cat ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt |awk -F'<' '{print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $10 ","$12"," $16 "," $23}'
```

Output:

```
2014-12-30 00:00:02,317 pool-14076-thread-3 DEBUG [com.fundamo.connector.airtime.service.AirtimeService] ERS Response XML - ,MessageID>1913351092,MessageRefID>BD9123000000003,StatusID>200,Comment>Transaction Successful,Amount>2000,PhoneNumber>1766910910
```

However, I only want the fields shown below.

```
2014-12-30 00:00:02,317 ,1913351092,BD9123000000003,200,Transaction Successful,2000,1766910910
```

What should I do?

Comment: @nu11p01n73R If data is in one line, you must make sure it stays in one line when you edit the post.  You did create 4 line from the single long line.

Comment: @Basudev you have two entry for `2000`, which one of them do you want in output? `<Amount>2000</Amount><AmountExcludingTax>2000</AmountExcludingTax>`. `<Amount>` value? or `<AmountExcludingTax>`?

Comment: my data is one line.....

Comment: @KasiyA: i want first value..<Amount>2000</Amount>

Comment: @nu11p01n73R No problem, Happy New Year :)

Comment: @Jotne Hha happy new year !!!

Comment: @Basudev I have deleted my answer and leave my command here `grep -oP '^.* (?=pool)|(?<=>).*?(?=<)' file`

Answer (score 2):

Here is how to do it with `awk`

```
awk -F"[ <>]" '{print $1" "$2,$18,$22,$28,$32" "$33,$41,$55}' OFS=, ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt
2014-12-30 00:00:02,317,1913351092,BD9123000000003,200,Transaction Successful,2000,1766910910
```

---

And here are some tip.

1. Try to find what separate every fields, her it would be , `<` and `>`
2. Then find all fields, by run it like this: `awk -F"[ <>]" '{for (i=1;i<=NF;i++) print i"="$i}' file`
3. Then its just to put it all together.

Comment: it is not working in my server...My server is like below.
SunOS ftpsvr 5.10 Generic_150401-09 i86pc i386 i86pc

i am getting almost whole value

Comment: @Basudev What is not working.  Do you get an error, wrong output? This `awk` does not using any special function, so it should work on most system.

Comment: i run below command....
cat ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt|awk -F"[ <>]" '{print $1,$2,$18,$22,$28,$32" "$33,$41,$55}' OFS=,

Is it ok?

Comment: You should never use `cat` with programs that can read data itself. It slows things down, you loose functions, uses more resources. So: `awk -F"[ <>]" '{print $1,$2,$18,$22,$28,$32" "$33,$41,$55}' OFS=, ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt`. Also its good to use space before and after pipes `|`.  Also use code tags in your post and comments use the "`" before and after text to mark.

Comment: Then your data is different from what you have posted here.  Try copy data from your post to a new file and test your command.  I have also given you the step on how to solve it your self. Find the separators, loop trough the file to get all fields number, put it then back.

Answer (score 0):

You can try sed as follows (this is a little long) followed by your file

```
sed 's#\([0-9]\{4\}-[0-9]\{2\}-[0-9]\{2\} [0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\}:[0-9]\{2\},\S*\).*<MessageID>\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\)<.*<MessageRefID>\([[:alpha:]]\{1,\}[[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*<StatusID>\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*\(Transaction Successful\).*<Amount>\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*<PhoneNumber>\([[:digit:]]\{1,\}\).*#\1 ,\2,\3,\4,\5,\6,\7#g'
```

replace `sed`  with `sed -i.bak` to make a back up of the original file and make actual changes,once this works (command line tested on my side)

Answer (score 0):

You need to use `nawk` on Solaris instead of `awk`. In Solaris' version of `awk`, the `-F` parameter can only take a single character, while in `nawk`, it can take a regular expression.

You need to specify the whole pattern of `<.....>` as a separator instead of just `<`:

This works on the Mac:

```
$ awk -F'<[^<]+>' '{print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $10 ","$12"," $16 "," $23}' ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt
```

Try the following on Solaris

```
$ nawk -F'<[^<]+>' '{print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $10 ","$12"," $16 "," $23}' ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt
```

If that doesn't work...

```
$ nawk -F'<[^<][^<]*>' '{print $1 "," $5 "," $7 "," $10 ","$12"," $16 "," $23}' ERS_RESPONSE_30Dec_atp11.txt
```